# Reroute Traffic to PHP Script From Specific Folder

Tags: php, .htaccess

I'm basically trying to build a tiny router that would take any traffic from "mysite.com/news/article_01"  and reroute that to a script living in the root "html" folder called "news.php"  where I'd capture the article name as a variable and deliver content from there.

The trick is I don't want to overwrite the current index.html file.

I found this little snippet:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
 
RewriteRule ^.*$ ./index.php
```

I have a feeling though that that would route ALL traffic to the php file which I don't want...

Thoughts?

Comment: Yes, that would route ALL traffic to the `index.php`. How else do you want to route?

Comment: I would like to only capture traffic that has "/news/" in the url

Comment: Then use `RewriteRule ^news/ index.php [L,NC]`

Comment: Can you please post that as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears for your requirement you may be able to use this more targeted rule:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^news/ index.php [L,NC]
```

This will only route `/news/` URIs to `index.php` instead of everything.

Comment: This is perfect... one tiny issue, it seems to be capturing mysite.com/news but not mysite.com/news/article

Comment: If you access `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` then it will show full URI

Comment: When I add the extra / to the domain It seems I'm getting a recursion error... "Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace." (500 error)

Comment: Do you have any other code in your .htaccess? And what is exact URL you request to get into `LimitInternalRecursion` ?

Comment: My bad, I did have a another rewrite to handle "pretty names"... Thank you again for your time!!